# deny use of method before a field has value

Tags: c#

I'll bet this is a pretty basic design question, but since it is hard for me to phrase it, i could not find any sources online to help me answer it. I'm using `C#6` and although it is a design question, I would also accept any answer that uses c#6 unique features.

my problem: say you have a simple class `MyClass` with property `MyProp`. `MyClass` also have the method:

```
public void InitializeMyProp(someValue)
{
   MyProp = //use the value of someValue to calculate MyProp
}
```

in addition, `MyClass` has many public methods, that uses MyProp, e.g.:

```
public int DependedMethod1()
{
   //use the value of MyProp to do some calculations. this method might also fail to initialize MyProp and I'm not sure how to handle this situation
   return valueThatDependOnMyProp1;
}
```

the value of `MyProp` is not known at time of instantiating `MyClass`. but, methods `DependedMethod1, DependedMethod2, ... , DependedMethodN` all depend on the value of `MyProp`.

my question: how do I make sure `MyProp` is initialized before using it?

I have some ideas, all of them I do not like:

1.of course, I can add the same code to each method `DependedMethod`:

`if(MyProp == null) throw exception()`

but this has three cons: a. duplicated code? b. exceptions require handling, every time I call the method.

2. as appose to my first (bad) idea, maybe prevent calling the methods before hand? say, put all `DependedMethods` in an inner (static?) class `InnerDependedClass`, assign to `MyClass` a field of type `InnerDependedClass` (lets name it `MyField`) and instantiate it at `InitializeMyProp`.

this is a reasonable solution because, if `InitializeMyProp` fails, I do not instantiate `MyField`. but the problem sticks - if other class will want to use the methods of `MyField` it will have to check if it is null before hand - and that's kinda like asking if `MyProp` is null.

I am still struggling to fully explain my self here.

my specific problem is this: given a binary file path, open the file, read the first 2 bytes in it (kind of an offset key), and save this key. keep the file in memory (I'm using InMemoryFileStream) because source might get deleted or changed. later on, when asked, extract specific info from the fileStream, using the key (again, an offset).
the problem is that if the file is corrupted/cannot be opened for read (for any reason), the key will be null.

I believe I have a big design issue here. my code is bellow

```
public class MyReaderStream : IDisposable, IMyReaderStream
{
    public MemoryStream InMemoryStream { get; }

    public MyReaderStream(string path)
    {
        InMemoryStream = GetInputFile(path);
        //if (InMemoryStream == null) throw new MyReaderException($"path {path} could not be found");
        if (InMemoryStream == null) InMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    }

    public MyReaderStream(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        InMemoryStream = stream;
        if (InMemoryStream == null) InMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        InMemoryStream?.Dispose();
    }

    public bool VerifyPath(string path)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
        if (extension != null && !extension.Equals(@".bin")) return false;
        return File.Exists(path);
    }

    public MemoryStream GetInputFile(string path)
    {
        if (!VerifyPath(path)) return null;

        MemoryStream inMemoryCopy = new MemoryStream();

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            fs.CopyTo(inMemoryCopy);
        }

        return inMemoryCopy;
    }
}
public class MyReader
{
    private readonly IMyReaderStream _stream;
    private uint? offset = null;

    public MyReader(IMyReaderStream stream)
    {
        this._stream = stream ?? new MyReaderStream(new MemoryStream());
    }

    public uint? GetKey()
    {
        try
        {
            offset = Helpers.ReadWord(_stream.InMemoryStream, 0);
            //might fail if file is corrupted

        }
        catch(Exception) {return null;}
    }
    public uint? FirstDependedMethod(){
       return  Helpers.ReadWord(_stream.InMemoryStream, offset + SOME_CONSTANT1); //if offset is null...?
        }
     //more methods like FirstDependedMethod
     //.....
     //.....
  }
```

**update**

this is a WPF MVVM project. the Model looks like this:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
 public class Model
 {
    private NvmReader _reader;

    public Model()
    {
        Reader = new NvmReader(null);
    }

    public NvmReader Reader
    {
        set { _reader = value; }
        get { return _reader; }
    }
}
```

and is initialized by the `ViewModel` like this:

```
this._model = new Model();
```

when the user chooses a path for the binary file, only then can the `NvmReader` object can get the needed offset

Comment: You should make sure all initialization is done within the constructor, so you can guarantee your instance methods will work.

Comment: ...and if you cannot then throw exception. You do not need to handle programming errors. Do you handle ArgumentNullException?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you cannot move `offset = Helpers.ReadWord(_stream.InMemoryStream, 0);` to the constructor?  It appears from what you have posted that the stream the object uses cannot be changed (it is only provided when the object is instantiated)... then `GetKey()` could just `return offest;`

Comment: to enable full initialization i need that the `stream` parameter to constructor will not be null and that the data in the stream will not be corrupted. i can call `offset = Helpers.ReadWord(_stream.InMemoryStream, 0);` in the constructor but it might fail or throw an exception. and then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split the class into 2 classes.

Let's say you start with a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Initialize(int value)
    {

    }

    public void MethodA() { }
    public void MethodB() { }
}
```

Both `MethodA` and `MethodB` require that the `Initialize` method is called first.

You can refactor this class into 2 separate classes. One will be responsible for implementing `MethodA` and `MethodB`, the other one for initialization. This way the type system will make sure that everything is initialized.

```
public class MyClassFactory
{
    public MyClass Create(int value)
    {
        return new MyClass(value);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    internal MyClass(int value)
    {

    }

    public void MethodA() { }
    public void MethodB() { }
}
```

Comment: i understand your solution but still have problem grasping the consequences of wrong path/value passed to me. please see my update.

Comment: @zook2005 You can validate and process the parameter in the `Create` method and throw an exception if it's incorrect.

Comment: The upside of this approach is that you cannot get access to the "portion" of the class that has the methods you want to call without going through the process of initializing it correctly. This is usually called either the factory pattern or the builder pattern.

Comment: isnt that like throwing the exception inside the constructor?

Comment: i can say that i see no other way. i need to do all the initialization in the constructor. if something goes wrong i should throw an exception (or return null if i use the factory pattern). the caller (of the constructor) should expect an error and handle it. it is just so disturbing because the `MyClass` object is a member of my solution's `Model`, and it cannot be instantiated until the `ModelView` will obtain the `filePath` from the user

Comment: @zook2005 Yes, but sometimes you are not able to call a constructor. For example if you're programming to an interface then constructors are implementation details. Also you might not be able to control the lifetime of the object (for example if it's injected using DI), there might be more methods that can be correctly called before initialization etc.

Comment: @zook2005 You might also consider splitting your view and viewmodel this way - one view that the user can work with to choose the path, another one to work with when the file is loaded correctly.